# How to make an IK chain stay above another IK chain

Tags: rigging, armature, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I modeled a recurve bow and now I'm rigging it. The wooden body of the bow bends correctly.

[image]

But at the start of the pulling motion the string's IK chain straightens and goes trough the tip curvature.

[image]

Any idea of how to constrain the string's IK chain so it always stays above the bow's IK chain?

Comment: Can you upload your file?
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/

Comment: I've uploaded the rig: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1223/

Answer (score 1):

In an IK chain, you can limit bone rotations to keep them within a certain range of movement. Select the base bone in your IK chain and limit one of its rotation values (in this case either X or Z) until the mesh doesn't intersect with the bow's arm. Repeat this process down the chain to get a nice curve running along the arm. When limiting, it is not necessary to set both negative and positive limits to custom values. Most of the time you will want to keep one side completely open (+-180 degrees) while limiting the other. These limit values have hard limits of +-180 degrees because any rotation beyond will simply flip the IK solution to the other side. For more intuitive and predictable visual feedback, I recommend putting your IK chain bones in one of the many Euler rotation modes.

[image: ik limits]